# Select from two tables by using a textbox value

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two tables and I want to search into them by using a `TextBox` and this is my code but wrong hope to help me

```
string constring = "Data Source =.; initial Catalog = business; Integrated Security=SSPI;";
SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(constring);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
if (txtID.Text.Trim() != "")
{
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select tab1.ID ,tab1.DATMOSTAND ,tab1.MONY ,tab2.BYAN ,tab2.MONY from MAL_ERTEBAT,tab2 where tab1.ID = tab2.EID = '" + txtID.Text + "'", CN);
    sda.Fill(dt);
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

where tab1.ID = tab2.EID = '" + txtID.Text + "'"  this is the error part the message is "in correct syntax near ="

Comment: Your code is susceptible to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack. Read up on the subject.

Comment: Now,what is your problem ? Are you getting any error?

Comment: @MahaSwetha: Am i correct?

Comment: where tab1.ID = tab2.EID = '" + txtID.Text + "'"  this is the error part the message is "in correct syntax near ="

Comment: you have to put `AND` in you query like so `where tab1.ID = tab2.EID AND tab2.EID = "' + txtID.Text + "'"`

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are missing the `alias` name:

Replace the above `SqlDataAdapter` with:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select tab1.ID ,tab1.DATMOSTAND ,tab1.MONY ,tab2.BYAN ,tab2.MONY from MAL_ERTEBAT tab1,tab2 where tab1.ID = tab2.EID = '" + txtID.Text + "'", CN);
```